# Javascript matrix array issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I'm creating a very simplified version of a drag and drop shopping cart with jqueryui.
My issue is regarding adding data(id, name, price) to an array.

I tried several methodes of adding the data (also an array) to the main container(array). But I keep getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
var data = [];
function addproduct(id,name,price){
    //var d = [id,name,price];
    data[id]["name"] = name;
    data[id]["price"] = price;
    data[id]["count"] = data[id]["count"]+1;
    console.log(data);
}
```

the addproduct() function can be called by pressing a button

Comment: it's console.log, not console.print

Comment: You will at least have to initialize `data[id] = {};` before adding properties to it.  Also, is `data` really an array with sequential numeric indexes?  Or should be you be using an object instead of an array.

Comment: @jfriend00 which would (further) break the counter field...

Comment: @Alnitak - the OP's question and code is not very clear, but my point was that you can't just execute `data[id]["name"] = name;` unless `data[id]` is already an object or an array so code somewhere has to initialize that the first time it is going to be used.  Usually, you check to see if it exists already and if not, you initialize it before attempting to assign properties to it.

Comment: console.print was a typo, I corrected it now.

so I want to use the id as identifier, so every time there is a new product, the product identifier is added along with the name of the product, price and the amount of it in the shopping cart. 

@jfriend00, do I have to manually initialize every id I wish to add?

Comment: Yes, you have to create an object before you can assign properties to it.  See my answer for one way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what type of data structure you want to end up with after you've added a number of items to the cart.  So, this answer is a guess based on what it looks like you're trying to do in your question, but if you show a Javascript literal for what you want the actual structure to look like after there are several items in the cart, we can be sure we make the best recommendation.

You have to initialize a javascript object or array before you can use it.  The usual way to do that is to check if it exists and if it does not, then initialize it before assigning to it. And, since you're keeping a `count`, you also will want to initialize the count.

```
var data = [];
function addproduct(id,name,price){
    if (!data[id]) {
        // initialize object and count
        data[id] = {count: 0};
    }
    data[id]["name"] = name;
    data[id]["price"] = price;
    ++data[id]["count"];
    console.log(data);
}
```

And FYI, arrays are used for numeric indexes.  If you're using property names like "name" and "price" to access properties, you should use an object instead of an array.

---

And, I would suggest that you use the dot syntax for known property strings:

```
var data = [];
function addproduct(id,name,price){
    if (!data[id]) {
        // initialize object and count
        data[id] = {count: 0};
    }
    data[id].name = name;
    data[id].price = price;
    ++data[id].count;
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: allright! thank you I spend 2 hours of head breaking on this thing :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is an array of objects, although I would need a more detailed description of your problem to be clear.

```
var data = []

function addproduct(id, name, price)
{
    data.push({'id': id, 'name':name, 'price': price, 'count': ++count});
    console.log(data);

}
```